# Using NNJoin-Plugin through Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2, nearest-neighbor

I want to write a Python script which I can execute from within QGIS 2.18 (from the Python console).

The Python script should calculate the nearest line (out of a set of lines) of a given point (out of a set of points) and I have already accomplished this task by manually using the NNJoin-Plugin. Now I want to automize this process within a python script, but I do not know how to run the [NNJoin plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/) within a Python script.

Is this even possible? If yes, could you give me some advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> from qgis import utils
>>> theplugin = utils.plugins['NNJoin']
>>> dir(theplugin)
```

That will give you

```
['NNJOIN', 'NNJOINAMP', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'dlg', 'iface', 'initGui', 'nnj_action', 'plugin_dir', 'run', 'toolbar', 'tr', 'unload']
```

---

**References:**

- [Can one expose variables to the Python console from a plugin in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/can-one-expose-variables-to-the-python-console-from-a-plugin-in-qgis)
- [How to show Python console at QGIS program start](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132695/how-to-show-python-console-at-qgis-program-start/132714#132714)
- [Accessing QGIS plugins in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/accessing-qgis-plugins-in-python)
- [Calling interpolation plugin from Python console of QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/calling-interpolation-plugin-from-python-console-of-qgis/233380)
- [How to run QGIS plugin from python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183035/how-to-run-qgis-plugin-from-python-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)